# Date input not being sent to Parse (works on all browsers except Chrome)

Tags: javascript, php, html, object

First I take the input in as:

```
<input id="orderTimeOne" name="orderTimeOne" type="time" value=<?php if(isset($_SESSION['orderTimeOne'])) { echo '"' . $_SESSION['orderTimeOne']='' . '"';} ?>>
```

So the id is `orderTimeOne` and the type is `time`

----------------Then on the next page:--------------------

if statement containing passed variables from session

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $_SESSION['orderTimeOne'] = $_POST['orderTimeOne'];
}   

if($_SESSION['orderTimeOne'] == '' || !isset($_SESSION['orderTimeOne']))
{
    $timeOne=0;
} else {
    $timeOne=1;
}
```

----------------Then on the next page:--------------------

```
<?php
    $orderTimeOne = $_SESSION['orderTimeOne'];
?>


<p id="FirstTime" style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $orderTimeOne;?> </p>
```

This echo's out the input of the date the user put from the starting page. 
Now this is the final page before the user presses confirm and it calls upon a `onclick` JS function. Which does this all in one function:

```
function() {
    var Booking = Parse.Object.extend("Booking");
    var firstOrderTime = document.getElementById('FirstTime').innerHTML;

    booking.save ({
        firstOrderTime: firstOrderTime
    });
}
```

`firstOrderTime` is the variable string set in Parse

Keep in mind this all works in Safari as well and FireFox, just not Chrome.

Comment: Are you including `session_start()` on each page requiring access to session information?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes I am, it's just the time input that doesn't work

Comment: @JayBlanchard Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you checked for JavaScript errors in the Chrome console? Does Parse use AJAX that can be monitored using the network panel?

Comment: Does p#FirstTime contain the correct value and just do not get retrieved or the value is missing too? Also: you declare a Booking variable and use booking.

Comment: @PrzemysławJanWróbel Yes when it echo's in FirstTime, the innerHTML is set to the correct time such as 01:00 or 13:00 for example

Comment: @halfer Yes I believe there is not JS errors unfortunately

Comment: What's the value of firstOrderTime variable in Chrome? `console.debug`

Comment: @PrzemysławJanWróbel So, firstOrderTime is set variable within the JS file from the innerHTML of FirstTime. So getting the innerHTML of FirstTime is what's being set to firstOrderTime. Seems like you're onto something here though

Comment: Yeah, I can see it within your code, but I would like you to check with `console.log` the exact value of this variable before saving a booking on FF and Chrome

Comment: @PrzemysławJanWróbel [Image Link](http://i.imgur.com/snnTWDE.png)

Comment: And what is sent to server?

Comment: @PrzemysławJanWróbel To Parse, when using Chrome, even though the value of this in console is shown (undefined) is still in the placement in Parse attribute. But when using Safari it works perfectly fine...

Comment: Console shows you undefined as the second result because it outputs what you write by default (the returned value of console.log), so it does not matter. What I want to know is what exactly is not working ;-)